Resizing retina screenshots for web
As far as I know, web browsers display images at 96 PPI.
And at least on my Mac, the screenshots created using the Screen Capture app are 144 PPI.
So, if I created a screenshot on my Mac and I want to upload it somewhere so that people will see it in the same size in which I see it on my Mac, I need to resize it at 66.6%:

[aside] Why 66.6? Here are my calculations: (96 / 144) * 100 = 66.6... Be aware that I'm not strong in math at all.

magick original.png -resize 66.6% resize66dot6.png


[aside] Here I use ImageMagick. The easiest way to install ImageMagick on Mac is brew install imagemagick

But in fact resize66dot6.png, if opened in a web browser (at least in Safari), is larger than it should be.
And to make the screenshot to be displayed in web browsers in the correct size, it seems I need to resize it to 50% or something very close, for some reason:
magick original.png -resize 50.0% resize50.png

From top to bottom: original.png, resize66dot6.png, resize50.png, and the actual UI element:

Why is it so?

"Web browsers display images at 96 PPI" not really. This is self-evident in that you can readily find 1920x1080 px displays that are (for example) 15 inches or 24 inches diagonally.
Browsers display 100% pixel size unless instructed by e.g. a style or html element.
The more basic answer though is: retina lies about pixel dimensions. Retina displays may be "set for 1080p" (for example) but the device may actually be creating and passing to the display 1.5-4 times as many pixels (depending on the screen). This results in crisper type etc. on those screens but it creates some confusion.
Decide on the pixel dimensions you are targeting and use that. The wiki page for Retina has a whole table of pixel sizes for various Apple products. It is not standardized and changes year by year and product by product.
As far as webpages go, Apple browsers using "Retina" look for images on your server that match the file name plus @2x appended. See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299807
